# R piping (%>%) does not work with replicate function

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

I am trying to learn the piping function (%>%).
When trying to convert from this line of code to another line it does not work.

---- R code -- original version -----

```
set.seed(1014)
replicate(6,sample(1:8))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    3    7    4    5    1
[2,]    2    8    4    2    4    2
[3,]    5    4    8    5    8    5
[4,]    3    1    2    1    1    7
[5,]    4    6    3    7    7    3
[6,]    6    5    1    3    3    8
[7,]    8    7    5    8    6    6
[8,]    7    2    6    6    2    4
```

---- R code - recoded with the pipe ----

```
> sample(1:8) %>%  replicate(6,.)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    7    7    7    7    7    7
[2,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
[3,]    2    2    2    2    2    2
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5    5
[6,]    4    4    4    4    4    4
[7,]    8    8    8    8    8    8
[8,]    6    6    6    6    6    6
```

Notice that when using pipes, the sampling does not work giving me
the same vector across.

Comment: In the first code, the replicate is executing the sample function 6 time. In the second code, you are given the output to the sample function and replicating that output 6 times.

Answer (score 21):

That's to be expected. replicate expects an expression, but when using the pipe operator as is you just paste the result of the call to `sample()` to `replicate`. So you get 6 times the same result.

You have to use `quote()` to pass the expression to replicate instead of the result, but you shouldn't forget to evaluate each of the repetitions of that expression.

```
quote(sample(c(1:10,-99),6,rep=TRUE)) %>% 
  replicate(6, .) %>%
  sapply(eval)
```

Gives:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    5    2   10   10    9    2
[2,]    4    3    1    3  -99    1
[3,]   10    2    3    8    2    4
[4,]  -99    1    6    2   10    3
[5,]    8  -99    1    9    4    6
[6,]    4   10    8    1  -99    8
```

What happens here:

- the piping sends and expression to replicate without evaluating it.
- replicate replicates that expression and returns a list with 6 times that expression but without evaluating it.
- sapply(eval) goes through the list and executes each expression in that list.

In your previous question (i.e. when using data.frame), you could have done eg:

```
quote(sample(c(1:10,-99),6,rep=TRUE)) %>% 
  replicate(6, .) %>%
  data.frame
```

Now the function `data.frame` would force the expressions to be executed, but you also end up with terrible variable names, i.e. the expression itself.

If you want to learn more about the issues here, you'll have to dive into what is called "lazy evaluation" and how that is dealt with exactly by the pipe operator. But in all honesty, I really don't see any advantage of using the pipe operator in this case. It's not even more readable.

As per Frank's comment: You can use a mixture of piping and nesting of functions to avoid the `sapply`. But for that, you have to contain the nested functions inside a code block or the pipe operator won't process it correctly:

```
quote(sample(c(1:10,-99),6,rep=TRUE)) %>% {
  replicate(6, eval(.)) }
```

Very interesting, but imho not really useful...

Comment: Thank you so much.  That makes so much sense.  Just trying to learn this stuff.  Yeah, may not make worth it to use pipes here but I was just learning.

Comment: I don't think sapply is needed: `quote(sample(c(1:10,-99),6,rep=TRUE)) %>% { replicate(6, eval(.)) }`

Comment: @Frank forget my previous comment, I missed the `{}` and the fact `eval()` is now nested inside `replicate`. That works indeed, but this is half piping, half not, so it makes even less sense. Thank you for mentioning it though, it's an interesting case. And yet another example as to why that pipe operator is a can of worms I'm reluctant to open. I added your proposal to the post though.

Comment: Ok, in my opinion, it's still piping, just not to the first argument of `replicate`. The magrittr rules for "guessing" when to pass `.` to the first argument are annoying, yeah. And also, for simulations, I wouldn't use pipes, ran a benchmark here (under "speed and pipes"): http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/work.html#simulations

Answer (score 0):

As of *R 4.1.0*, a new pipe `|>` is [available](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/the-new-r-pipe/) which does work with replicate.

```
library(magrittr)
set.seed(123)
runif(1) %>%
  replicate(n = 4)
# 0.2875775 0.2875775 0.2875775 0.2875775
runif(1) |>
  replicate(n = 4)
# 0.7883051 0.4089769 0.8830174 0.9404673
```